# Sqoop to write column names as headers

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm importing a table of data from Oracle into HDFS.
I need to have Sqoop to write the column names as headers into the import files (files that end up in HDFS). Is there a way to do that? I basically need the import file to look like the following:

ID, Country, City

1,USA,Palo Alto

2,Czech Republic,Brno

3,USA,Sunnyvale

instead of the following:

1,USA,Palo Alto

2,Czech Republic,Brno

3,USA,Sunnyvale

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there isn't.

Typically HDFS files do not have headers as they would treated as data by components like Hive and Pig, or would require special treatment in programming frameworks like MapReduce and Spark.

If you want to carry the schema with the data then you might consider having Sqoop save the data in Avro format.